# How to use browser on terminal on Mac?

Tags: terminal

I have a mac and I want to use browser on terminal. I found resources for Ubuntu and CentOS.

I am using brew package manager and iTerm.

How can I use for Mac?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use w3m on the Mac. Do `brew install w3m` on iTerm.

In your shell browse like `w3m google.com`.

Here is proper documentation http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL.